# c#, find multiline message by regex request

Tags: c#, regex, multiline

Main task
Find all DEBUG messages and select message fully (no matter single line message or multiline with unknown length)

I wrote such regex code:

```
\d{13}\t.*DEBUG.*(?=\d{13})
```

its search perfectly, but only single-line messages

Also I tried such code:

```
string myReg1 = @"\d{13}\t.*DEBUG.*(?=\d{13})";
            MatchCollection match1 = Regex.Matches(logData, myReg1, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

but this code found only one mach, where must be 147 matches....

I have logs like this:

```
1426174736798   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for OpenH264Provider

1426174736799   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
*** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
```

Comment: Did it match the first Debug message and all but the last line?  If so, I think you just need to make the `.*` after `DEBUG` not greedy `.*?`.

Comment: looks like yes, all up to the end of line. I tried to write ".*?", but result was the same...

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/lvH1vTk.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this non-greedy regex instead (EDIT: tweaked a bit for input):

```
\d{13}\t.{0,100}DEBUG.+?(?=\d{13}|$)
```

Now this is tweaked a bit more closely to your input data.  I can't really think of an ideal way to keep that first dot before the `DEBUG` from eating up other rows that you don't want.  In a perfect world, you could write a phrase to say something like, "any character except a row of 13 digits", but this is not really something that regex does well.  Maybe someone else can make this better.  In the meantime, I have restricted the first dot to consume no more than 100 characters.  If it goes more than 100 characters past the 13 digit number and has not found the string "DEBUG" yet, it is fairly safe to assume it is on a row we don't care about.  You may need to tweak this number up or down a bit to fit your data (and I hate imperfect solutions like this), but hopefully this will get you in the neighborhood.

Changing `.*` to `.+?` makes the dot non-greedy.  I also added an `or` to the last non-capturing group with a `$` to match end-of-line (`RegexOptions.SingleLine` will treat the entire input as one line) to ensure that your last record is captured, since there will be no 13 digit number following the end of it.

This appears to work correctly in [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm), which uses the same regex engine as .NET

Comment: Thanks a lot, its much better result, but still not perfect. Try to check this document: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5732489/LogsExample.txt -- your C# regex found exactly 142 matches (in this log is really 142 DEBUG messages), but some of found matches is wrong: http://i.imgur.com/ZStoiH1.png . Thanks a lot for your assistance!

Comment: Oh, I see what is going on.  If you look all the way to the right of that circled item, you will eventually see the word DEBUG.  That `.+?` in front has gobbled up the INFO lines, thinking they were part of the text between the 13-digit number and the "DEBUG" text.  Give me a few minutes and I'll take a closer look